# Call to reload functions/aliases in a script after it runs in Windows PowerShell is not working

Tags: powershell

I wrote this small alias script to set up some settings but somehow I can not get this to work that the aliases are reloaded with one function/alias. Under Linux
I just do source file and it reloads it inside the script and I have the new aliases
available.

Under windows 10/powershell 7.2 I have tried with .,  with &, with a function, with calling another script or whatever ..nothing works. So I have to type . repo for reloading the aliases after the script exits
manually.

So as state nothing worked inside that function eal. Examples I found include

```
. repo
. $profile
. aliases.ps1
& $profile
```

are not reloading the settings in the current session.

Any ideas how to edit a file with aliases and then reload after the editing in
the current shell?

```
#Set Paths
$Env:PATH += ";C:\Tools\git\usr\bin"
#Aliases

Set-Alias wo Write-Output
Set-Alias ll ls
Set-Alias lld ls
Set-Alias tc 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Total Commander\TCUP64.exe'


# Utilities since windows can not do multiple commands in one alias
#

#function to reload the profile
function repo  {
    @(
            $Profile.AllUsersAllHosts,
            $Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost,
            $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts,
            $Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
      ) | % {
            if(Test-Path $_){
            Write-Verbose "Running $_"
      . $_
       }
   }    
}

#edit aliases, functions
function eal {
 vim $env:USERPROFILE\.config\aliases.ps1 
 Write-Output "Please run . repo to reload the profile"
 $alias_config = Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE .config\aliases.ps1
// any code to put here to reload the file?
// . $profile etc nothing works
// . or & path to aliases.ps1 does not work in any way either
}

function epro {
 vim $env:USERPROFILE\.config\powershell\user_profile.ps1
 Write-Output "Please run . repo to reload the profile"
}

function which ($command) {
  Get-Command -Name $command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

function .. {
    cd ..
}
```

Comment: You never dot-source `aliases.ps1` anywhere ...

Comment: I added the note where any code I tried is not working thanks